# Como ir para uma ancora em uma página com pouco conteúdo?

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Estou criando uma página utilizando [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) e gostaria de colocar algumas ancoras em locais específicos, acontece que como a página tem pouco conteúdo, o elemento que representa a ancora não vai para o topo quando clico no link que redireciona para ele, o exemplo abaixo produz exatamente o que acontece.

```css
.div-margin {
    margin-top: 80px
}
```

```html
<a href="#l1">Ir para l1</a><br/>
<a href="#l2">Ir para l2</a><br/>
<a href="#l3">Ir para l3</a><br/>
<div id="l1" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l1</p></div>
<div id="l2" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l2</p></div>
<div id="l3" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l3</p></div>
```

Nesse exemplo somente o **Você está na div-l1** fica no topo da página quando clico em **Ir para l1**, os outros dois não funcionam de maneira semelhante, o que fazer para que ambos funcionem da mesma maneira, ou seja, fiquem no topo da página quando eu clicar no link correspondente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque não existe espaço suficiente na página para a div ir até o topo, a página chega até onde pode. O ideal seria você encher a página de alguma forma, por exemplo, colocar `min-height: 100%;` nas divs, assim elas teriam no mínimo a altura da janela do navegador.

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

.div-margin {
    margin-top: 80px;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#l1">Ir para l1</a><br/>
<a href="#l2">Ir para l2</a><br/>
<a href="#l3">Ir para l3</a><br/>
<div id="l1" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l1</p></div>
<div id="l2" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l2</p></div>
<div id="l3" class="div-margin"><p>Você está na div-l3</p></div>
```