# Como fazer uma link para uma parte de uma pagina html

Tags: html, link

Como faço para que um link seja capaz de entrar na página e ir na seção escolhida? tipo um href na mesma pagina mudando para a parte de baixo do site, mas conseguindo fazer isso de outro site

Comment: pq não usa uma ancora para isso? é a forma mais simples de fazer iss no html

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como ir para uma ancora em uma página com pouco conteúdo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57063/como-ir-para-uma-ancora-em-uma-p%c3%a1gina-com-pouco-conte%c3%bado)

Answer (score 0):

Marque uma seção com o atributo 'id'

```
<div id='iddasecao'>
 <p>Alguma coisa</p>
</div>
```

e coloque na url a referência para esse id: [www.meusite.com.br/contato#iddasecao](http://www.meusite.com.br/contato#iddasecao)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).